# SSRS Atom Data Feed With No Identifier

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, atom-feed

I'm trying to follow the [SSRS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/generate-data-feeds-from-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs) to build an Atom-Compliant data feed based off of one of my reports.

Environment: SSRS 2012 Integrated into Sharepoint 2013
Report: Contains Map and Tablix (both should generate data feeds)

I understand that you have to download the atom service document and that it should contain the data feed URL but I'm stuck because the URLs in the service doc do not have an ID like the documentation says that they will. Instead the URL ends with:

```
Command=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=ATOM&amp;rc%3AItemPath=Tablix1
```

Which just runs the report if I try to navigate to this link.

Full service doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <workspace>
      <atom:title>Countries.rdl</atom:title>
      <collection href="https://hr.company.com/dashboards/gwa/_vti_bin/ReportServer?https%3a%2f%2fhr.company.com%2fdashboards%2fgwa%2fexec-DEV%2fReports%2fOverview+Reports%2fCountries.rdl&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=ATOM&amp;rc%3AItemPath=Map2.Map2_PolygonLayer1_Group">
         <atom:title>Map2</atom:title>
      </collection>
      <collection href="https://hr.company.com/dashboards/gwa/_vti_bin/ReportServer?https%3a%2f%2fhr.company.com%2fdashboards%2fgwa%2fexec-DEV%2fReports%2fOverview+Reports%2fCountries.rdl&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=ATOM&amp;rc%3AItemPath=Tablix1">
         <atom:title>Tablix1</atom:title>
      </collection>
   </workspace>
</service>
```

How can I generate the Atom Feed ID????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there isn't an atom identifier due to the fact that there is no device setting for ATOM in rsreportserver.config file.